# Bad system call when running Debian's static busybox on Android

Tags: android, busybox

Running the Debian's static arm64 BusyBox on my phone without any argument works, but if I choose to run busybox bc, it ends up with "bad system call" error.

1. Is it caused by the differences between the standard Linux kernel and the Android one?
2. Do you think it will work if I compile static busybox from source using Android NDK?

Comment: Running it using proot -0 helps to get BusyBox bc working: 
  https://github.com/MasterDevX/Termux-Java/issues/3 (issue with solution)   https://github.com/proot-me/proot-static-build/blob/master/static/proot-arm64 (working proot)

Answer (score 2):

It happens because newer libc tries modern syscalls (faccessat2 typically) not implemented in older kernels. In normal situation this just returns an error but in android seccomp filter installed to zygote crashes calling process.
This will not happen if your process is started not from zygote tree.
For example, from su shell of magisk